# Trouble using Dapper to call stored procedure from C#

Tags: c#, sql-server, dapper

I am completely new to C#, T-SQL, and Dapper and was trying to execute a stored procedure, but I am getting

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Incorrect syntax around 'Josh'

My stored procedure is simply:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [compName\Josh].[josh_test_insert]
    @ssn FLOAT,
    @gpa FLOAT
AS 
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    INSERT INTO [compName\Josh].josh_testing 
    VALUES (@ssn, @gpa);
END
GO
```

Where josh_testing has two fields of SSN and GPA.

The C# code is

```
public void InsertPerson(float ssn, float gpa)
{
    using (IDbConnection connection = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection(Helper.CnnVal("SampleDB")))
    {
        List<new_app> apps = new List<new_app>();
        apps.Add(new new_app { ssn = ssn, gpa = gpa });
        connection.Execute("compName\\Josh.josh_test_insert @ssn, @gpa",apps);
    }
}
```

Anyone know what I'm missing here?

Comment: In addition to escaping the name properly, it might be necessary to set the command type, like [shown in their documentation](https://tfs2.healthcarepayment.com/tfs/Development/Stingray4/_workitems?id=35885&_a=edit);.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just escape the name of the sp as you would do in Management Studio:

```
public void InsertPerson(float ssn, float gpa)
{
    using (IDbConnection connection = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection(Helper.CnnVal("SampleDB")))
    {
        connection.Execute("EXEC [compName\\Josh].[josh_test_insert] @ssn, @gpa", new { ssn = ssn, gpa = gpa });
    }
}
```

And pass the parameters without useless `List<>`s.